# Loopback.js How to use connector-rest?

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm trying to make an example app with connector-rest.

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest

My goal is making the following api.

```
$ curl http://localhost:3001/addresses/17F54d4S9aLpvUEsk7MkYWafmzxJhhb9wW/balance
{
  "balance": 42030
}
```

The balance is retrieved from blockchain.info api.

```
$ curl https://blockchain.info/balance?active=17F54d4S9aLpvUEsk7MkYWafmzxJhhb9wW
{"17F54d4S9aLpvUEsk7MkYWafmzxJhhb9wW": {
    "final_balance": 42030,
    "n_tx": 2,
    "total_received": 42030
}}
```

The followings are what I've done.

1. Create Loopback app
2. Create Rest datasource
3. Create Address model

But I don't know what should I do next? I think I need to configure something for request. Should I add it into datasources.json? How to call it from addresses.js?

My code is saved on github. https://github.com/y-zono/loopback-connector-rest-example

---

Update 1

I found this example.

https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-example-connector/tree/rest

Then, I could fetch data from blockchain.info.

https://github.com/y-zono/loopback-connector-rest-example/commit/f5e8f96a666f4fdab5d554e657f630635237c2c1

Still not sure whether this is normal way or not. I'm checking about that.

Answer (score 1):

I found it and I confirmed Promise and async/await work well.

Any suggestions are welcome and appreciated when you have any other better ways.

*address.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (Address) {

    async function getBalanceFromBlockchainInfo(address) {
        const blockchaininfo = Address.app.dataSources.blockchaininfo;
        try {
            const data = await Promise.all([
                blockchaininfo.balance(address),
                blockchaininfo.balance(address)
            ])
            return { "balance": data[0][address]["final_balance"], "unconfirmed_balance": data[0][address]["final_balance"] };
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    Address.getBalance = function (address, callback) {
        getBalanceFromBlockchainInfo(address).then(data => callback(null, data)).catch(err => callback(err));
    };

    Address.remoteMethod("getBalance", {
        http: { verb: "get", path: "/:address/balances" },
        accepts: [
            { arg: "address", type: "string", required: true }
        ],
        returns: { type: "object", root: true }
    });
};
```

*datasources.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "blockchaininfo": {
    "name": "blockchaininfo",
    "connector": "rest",
    "operations": [
      {
        "template": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://blockchain.info/balance",
          "query": {
            "active": "{address}"
          }
        },
        "functions": {
          "balance": [
            "address"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://github.com/y-zono/loopback-connector-rest-example

Comment: 1). You can use "baseUrl" property for "blockchaininfo" datasource to avoid url prefix duplication if you will need additional services
2). You can set "blockchaininfo" datasource for "Address" model and you will have balance() function out of box (not sure about remote method)